# Count the frequency of words used in a text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm an Elastic beginner and I have trouble understanding how to find the most popular search terms used by my users.

Each time a user searches for something, Logstash enters a document such as this in Elastic:

```json
{
  "_index" : "user_searches-2022.02.14",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "xGQA-H4BVgDEPVU6QZPf",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "message" : """[Large line in apache combined log format]""",
    "@timestamp" : "2022-02-14T11:31:13.395Z",
    "search_string": "hello world",
    "search_terms" : ["hello", "world"]
  }
},
```

The `search_string` is extracted from the URL; the `search_terms` is the `search_string` splitted (only one of these is needed, but I'm not yet certain which one).

I can't figure out what query can give me the counts of the search terms. I've had some success using `"significant_text": {"field: "search_string"}`, but it treats the whole string as a term, it doesn't split it into words. `_termvectors`, on the other hand, appears to only work on a single document, not on the entire index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it in the end, without changing anything else:

```
GET /user_searches-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "search_term_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "search_terms.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count `hello` and `world` separately and I assume that type of `search_terms` is `text` in your mapping. If so, if you set `fielddata` to `true`in your mapping for `search_terms` field, you can use terms aggregation as below to get the count of each word.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#enable-fielddata-text-fields

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "asd": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "search_terms",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that usign fielddata=true for text fields can cause high memory usage.

If `search_terms` field's type is `keyword` in the index mapping, you should be able to get the count with the above query without setting fielddata

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm not understanding something about `_source`. It is my understanding that `_source` isn't indexed and that I can't search its fields. Therefore I need to get `search_terms` out of `_source`. Is that correct? I can't figure out how I can do that.

Comment: See the following documentation. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html)

It depends on how you index fields of your document. For strings, you can use `text` or `keyword` field types in the mapping. Elasticsearch index strings as `keyword` default unless you change it in the mapping. `keyword` fields do not pass through any anaylzer. So they are indexed as they are, without splitted into tokens. You can use term filters to filter or terms aggregation and because they do not passed through any analyzer words in the string will not be splitted.

Comment: `text` fields pass through analyzers and elasticsearch split string into tokens according to analyzer used. You can use match queries to search. But it is not best practice to run aggregation on text fields. That's why you need to set fielddata=true to aggregate a `text` field.
If you want to aggregate splitted field without setting fielddata=true, you need to set that field to `keyword` in the mapping.

Comment: Fields in `_source` are indexed and they are indexed as default unless you change it. `search_terms` will stay in the `_source`, but you should update its mapping.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html